# Oracle Database 11g <> Operations in Oracle for CHAR(1 BYTE),

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an oracle table with this field

```
"SYSTEM_HIDDEN" CHAR(1 BYTE),
```

I have a row id (26119) with NULL value of this field. But when I query this row with this statement, return no rows:

```
SELECT * FROM T_BOOK WHERE id =26119 and SYSTEM_HIDDEN <> 'T'
```

in Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm, escpecially section "nulls with comparison conditions"

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` values behave special in all comparisons (except `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`), comparing `NULL` with `=`, `<>`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` always returns `NULL` which eventually behaves like `FALSE` in respect to not selecting any rows.

use `(SYSTEM_HIDDEN <> 'T' or SYSTEM_HIDDEN IS NULL)` or
    `NVL(SYSTEM_HIDDEN, 'F') <> 'T'` instead